# Does GPS cause the phone to get hot?

Tags: battery, gps

I am using a Moto G device and I have noticed that when I turn on applications that rely on the GPS [Waze](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.waze) or [Mapquest](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mapquest.android.ace), the device gets hot. As in hot to touch. I was previously using a Samsung Galaxy Tablet and I never noticed this.

What causes the device to get hot? Should I be returning my device to Motorola and asking for a refund?

Comment: They probably use a lot of "machine power". That's at least known for "continuous location with screen on" solutions (navigation etc).

Comment: Short answer yes: you've another chip to power and as Izzy said the screen stays on, the internet is working as it goes, so it gets warmer with location / GPS on. If it is too hot to touch something could be wrong, but all my devices get very, very warm after about 10 minutes of GPS. The worst enemy of your battery is heat, so this may be an issue if used daily for a long time. But it is normal, it just depends on HOW hot, what temp is your battery at?